# Python, convert dictionary to comma separated values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I need to convert the values in dict to comma separated so I can pass it to a dataclass directly.

I referred to - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30024695/3127144) & [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66691522/3127144)

***Code:***

```
d = {'Exch': 'N', 'ExchType': 'C', 'Signal': 1660,
     'Price': 207.75, 'date': '/Date(1626690582000)/'}
print(",".join(d.keys()))
print(",".join(d.values()))
```

But in my case, the keys get printed, but I get an error as below for values (Note: the values in dict are of different data types):

```
Exch,ExchType,Signal,Price,date
    print(",".join(d.values()))
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, int found
```

Pardon if this query is elementary, as am quite new to Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the value of the `Price` key is not a string.

To fix it try a list comprehension:

```
print(",".join([str(i) for i in d.values()]))
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Sorry, if you don't mind, can you let me know, will the conversion to comma separated maintain the initial dictionary sequence in all cases or will the sequence get distorted after conversion in some cases?

Comment: @iCoder Sorry but could you please clarify what you mean by "distorted".

Comment: You don't need the comprehension with the generator btw, you can just do `print(",".join(str(i) for i in d.values()))`

Comment: @SimonT Well I always go by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-in-python/9061024#9061024) answer.

Comment: @U11-Forward by distorted I mean:
Eg: expected - N,C,1660,207.75,/Date(1626690582000)/ 
   distorted - N,C,/Date(1626690582000)/,1660,207.75 or
               1660,207.75,N,C,/Date(1626690582000)/

Comment: @iCoder You mean disorted?

Comment: @U11-Forward yes, because I read in this forum in one of the threads, since it is dict, the order cannot be guaranteed. So wanted to be sure when the values are comma separated as above, it does not change the order in some cases

Comment: @iCoder Dictionaries are ordered since Python 3.6